# CSS: Display inline or block based on text width - no javascript

Tags: html, css

So I have the following DOM

```
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="first-child">Some Text</div>
    <div class="second-child">Some other text that can sometimes be very long, sometimes short</div>
  </div>
```

I want the `.second-child` to be `display: inline` with the `.first-child` if it is less than `500px`. I want it `display: block` otherwise.

I am looking for a pure CSS solution, no javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You can use flexbox to simulate such behavior:

```css
.parent {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.first-child {
  border:1px solid green;
  flex-basis:calc(100% - 500px); /*This will make the element to wrap when the second one is bigger than 500px*/
}
.second-child {
   border:1px solid red;
}

* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="first-child">Some Text</div>
    <div class="second-child">shot text (less than 500px)</div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="first-child">Some Text</div>
    <div class="second-child">medium text but still shorter to not wrap (less than 500px)</div>
  </div>

  <div class="parent">
    <div class="first-child">Some Text</div>
    <div class="second-child">very long text  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam tincidunt sagittis orci nec accumsan. Phasellus quis dui eu dolor pellentesqu (bigger than 500px)</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi Temani, thanks for your quick answer and interest in my problem ! You missed a little detail: the condition is on the width of the second-child, not the first-child

Comment: looks good but still not exactly what I need. Could you get ride of the margin on the right of "Some Text" ? The green box shouldn't be bigger than the text it contains.

Comment: @Paul I will think about  a way even if it seems a bit impossible

Comment: Wouldn't adding `flex-grow: 1;` on `.first-child` just work ?

Comment: @BenPog we need the exact opposite ;) we want the green one to shrink to content size